# Ellipsis in the middle of a text (Mac style)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, truncation

I need to implement ellipsis (`"..."`) in the middle of a text within a resizable element. [Here](http://i40.tinypic.com/29yqslf.jpg) is what it might look like. So,

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut ornare dignissim ligula sed commodo."
```

becomes

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ... commodo."
```

When the element is stretched out to the width of the text, I want the ellipsis to disappear. How can this be done?

Comment: I'd be interested to see your final implementation if you have it. :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In the HTML, put the full value in a custom data-* attribute like

```
<span data-original="your string here"></span>
```

Then assign `load` and `resize` event listeners to a JavaScript function which will read the original data attribute and place it in the `innerHTML` of your span tag. Here is an example of the ellipsis function:

```
function start_and_end(str) {
  if (str.length > 35) {
    return str.substr(0, 20) + '...' + str.substr(str.length-10, str.length);
  }
  return str;
}
```

Adjust the values, or if possible, make them dynamic, if necessary for different objects. If you have users from different browsers, you can steal a reference width from a text by the same font and size elsewhere in your dom. Then interpolate to an appropriate amount of characters to use.

A tip is also to have an abbr-tag on the ... or who message to make the user be able to get a tooltip with the full string.

```
<abbr title="simple tool tip">something</abbr>
```

Comment: This ended up being the best basis for my final solution. With a few extra lines of JavaScript code it does exactly what I wanted it to do.
I have decided to use "title" instead of the custom tag so now it provides accessibility naturally.

Thanks Stefan, John, and Kgiannakakis!

Comment: @user102465 Can you share the final result? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a css only way? Fixing it in UI itself rather than using the javsacript?

Comment: You can actually use `str.substr(-10)` for the second part.

Comment: if we implement ellipsis and try to copy the content on which ellipsis is applied, it copies ... instead of actual value.
Example: 
Actual value: abcdefghij,
Display on UI: abcd...hij,
Copied Value: abcd...hij

How to get the actual value while coping?

Comment: `substr` is deprecated, you should use it.

Answer (score 42):

I'd like to propose mine example of solving this problem.

The main idea is to split text in two even parts (or first is bigger, if the length is odd) one of which has ellipsis in the end and another aligned right with `text-overflow: clip`.

So all you need to do with js, if you want to make it automatic/universal - is to split string and set attributes.

It has some disadvantages, though.

1. No nice wrapping by words, or even letters (`text-overflow: ''` works only in FF at the moment)
2. If the split happens between words - space should be in the first part. Otherwise, it will be collapsed.
3. End of the string should not have any exclamation marks, due to `direction: rtl` - they will be moved to the left of the string. I think, it is possible to fix this with putting right part of the word in the tag and exclamation mark in the `::after` pseudo-element. But I haven't yet made it properly working.

But, with all of these, it looks really cool to me, especially when you dragging the border of the browser, which you can do on the jsfiddle page easily: https://jsfiddle.net/extempl/93ymy3oL/.
Or just run the snippet with fixed max-width below.

Gif under the spoiler:

> [image: Gif]

```css
body {
  max-width: 400px;
}

span::before, span::after {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
}

span::before {
  content: attr(data-content-start);
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

span::after {
  content: attr(data-content-end);
  text-overflow: '';
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<span data-content-start="Look deep into nature, and then you " 
      data-content-end=  "will understand everything better"></span>

<br>
<span data-content-start="https://www.google.com.ua/images/branding/g" 
      data-content-end=  "ooglelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"></span>
```

Comment: Is there a workaround for `text-overflow: '';` for chrome? Strings aren't supported as a value;

Comment: @jaysonder Unfortunately, no css-only workaround so far. It still works only in FF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#Browser_compatibility

Comment: The above snippet seems to run fine in chrome albeit, the text clipping can look a little funny for the second half.

Comment: I like this solution because it's really performant; no JavaScript.

Comment: The `direction: rtl` will mess up the second half of the text e.g. moving spaces or - characters to the left

Answer (score 13):

So my colleague came up with a solution that uses no extra dom elements.  We check to see if the div overflows and add a data attribute of the last n characters. The rest is done in css.

Here is some HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="ellipsis" data-tail="some">This is my text it is awesome</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="ellipsis">This is my text</div>
</div>
```

And  the css:

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
}

.ellipsis:before {
    float: right;
    content: attr(data-tail);
}

.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the obligatory jsfiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/r96vB/1/

Comment: Really nice solution, but unfortunately it does not work in Firefox 34 (text overlaps) and IE < 10 (unsupported method querySelector)

Comment: I like this solution.   Works in Safari (mac), FF 57, Edge, and Chrome 66.

Comment: Almost, but JS needs to be executed every time the box width changes, otherwise the :after content remains stuck :(

Answer (score 8):

The following Javascript function will do a middle truncation, like OS X:

```
function smartTrim(string, maxLength) {
    if (!string) return string;
    if (maxLength < 1) return string;
    if (string.length <= maxLength) return string;
    if (maxLength == 1) return string.substring(0,1) + '...';

    var midpoint = Math.ceil(string.length / 2);
    var toremove = string.length - maxLength;
    var lstrip = Math.ceil(toremove/2);
    var rstrip = toremove - lstrip;
    return string.substring(0, midpoint-lstrip) + '...' 
    + string.substring(midpoint+rstrip);
}
```

It will replace characters in the middle with ellipsis.  My unit tests show:

```
var s = '1234567890';
assertEquals(smartTrim(s, -1), '1234567890');
assertEquals(smartTrim(s, 0), '1234567890');
assertEquals(smartTrim(s, 1), '1...');
assertEquals(smartTrim(s, 2), '1...0');
assertEquals(smartTrim(s, 3), '1...90');
assertEquals(smartTrim(s, 4), '12...90');
assertEquals(smartTrim(s, 5), '12...890');
assertEquals(smartTrim(s, 6), '123...890');
assertEquals(smartTrim(s, 7), '123...7890');
assertEquals(smartTrim(s, 8), '1234...7890');
assertEquals(smartTrim(s, 9), '1234...67890');
assertEquals(smartTrim(s, 10), '1234567890');
assertEquals(smartTrim(s, 11), '1234567890');
```

Comment: This is great and works as described, however I have a need to make the output string "stretchable", so that the truncation is determined based on one's viewport size. Huge screen—no truncation, narrow screen—string is truncated using a dynamically calculated number of characters for best fit.

Comment: You'll have to attach an event handler to its container, which will then calculate the appropriate maxLength in relation to the container width property.  If your font-family is monospaced, this will be easy; if proportional, then you'll need to experiment to get the right heuristic.

Comment: To point out, this will works as expected only for fixed-width font displaying. On variable width fonts the display length of the text is not precisely correlated with the length in characters.

Answer (score 6):

After some research on flex boxes I found this pure CSS solution which I believe is pretty cool.

```
<div style="width:100%;border:1px solid green;display:inline-flex;flex-wrap:nowrap;">
   <div style="flex: 0 1 content;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;"> Her comes very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long </div>
   <div style="flex: 1 0 content;white-space:nowrap;"> &nbsp;but flexible line</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't think this answers the question. This does not solve the issue of adding an ellipsis in the middle of _1_ string. This simply adds an ellipsis between 2 strings. I.e., in the scenario of @user102465 the string first has to be split somehow for your solution to work.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a bit late in the game, but I was looking to find a solution to this, and a colleague suggested a very elegant one, which I'll share. It requires some JS, but not a lot.

Imagine you have a `div` of a size you need to put your label into:

```
<div style="width: 200px; overflow: hidden"></div>
```

Now, you have a function which will take two params: a string with the label, and a DOM element (this `div`) to fit it into:

```
function setEllipsisLabel(div, label)
```

The first thing you do is create a `span` with this label, and put it into the `div`:

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(label));
span.style.textOverflow = 'ellipsis';
span.style.display = 'inline-block';
div.appendChild(span);
```

We set the `text-overflow` property to "ellipsis" so that as the text gets chopped off, a nice "..." is added at the end to illustrate this. We also set `display` to be "inline-block" so that these elements have real pixel dimensions we can manipulate later. So far, nothing we could not have done with pure CSS.

But we want the ellipsis in the middle. First, we should find out if we need it at all... This can be done by comparing `div.clientWidth` to `span.clientWidth` - ellipsis is only needed if the `span` is wider than the `div`.

If we do need an ellipsis, let's start by saying that we want a fixed number of characters shown at the end of the word - say 10. So let's create a span containing only the last 10 characters of the label, and stick it into the div:

```
var endSpan = document.createElement('span');
endSpan.style.display = 'inline-block';
endspan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(label.substring(label.length - 10)));
div.appendChild(endSpan);
```

Now, let's override the width of the original `span` to accommodate the new one:

```
span.style.width = (div.clientWidth - endSpan.clientWidth) + 'px';
```

As a result of this, we now have a DOM structure that looks something like this:

```
<div style="width: 200px; overflow: hidden">
   <span style="display: inline-block; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 100px">
      A really long label is shown in this span
   </span>
   <span style="display: inline-block"> this span</span>
</div>
```

Because the first `span` has `text-overflow` set to "ellipsis", it will show "..." at the end, followed by the 10 characters of the second span, resulting in the ellipsis showing approximately in the middle of the `div`.

You don't need to hardcode the 10 character length for the endSpan either: this can be approximated by calculating ratio of the `span`'s initial width to that of the `div`, subtracting the appropriate proportion from the length of the label and dividing by two.

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions that I saw here take into account that different characters have different width.
My solution takes this into account. Basically, it strips text by one character until it fits, take a look:

```js
const span = document.getElementById("span");
const div = document.getElementById("div");
const originalText = span.textContent;
const textLength = originalText.length;
let part1 = originalText.substr(0, Math.floor(textLength / 2));
let part2 = originalText.substr(Math.floor(textLength / 2));
let trimPart1 = true;
while (span.clientWidth > div.clientWidth) {
  if (trimPart1) {
    part1 = part1.substr(0, part1.length - 1);
  } else {
    part2 = part2.substr(-1 * (part2.length - 1));
  }
  span.textContent = part1 + "..." + part2;
  trimPart1 = !trimPart1;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" style="overflow: hidden; width: 200px; white-space: nowrap;">
  <span id="span" style="display: inline-block">this is a quite long text that has some words and I want it to be split in half</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/maxim_mazurok/oujctpz8/56/

Mac's Finder works the same way, it first tries to strip the left part, then the right part. So, it may have `WWWW...WWWWW`, just as my solution.

It's not the most efficient one though. Perhaps, the same can be achieved using virtual DOM or canvas to better optimize performance.

Comment: An improvement that doesn't take the container into account, and solely looks at the text element: https://jsfiddle.net/AmitBecken/sva5teym/2/. Useful when the text element is adjacent to other elements that can affect its width.

Comment: the ellipsis is a modification of _display_, not content, so e.g. screen readers should not be reading out your modified textContent with the middle cut out and replaced by dots.  See my answer for how you could adapt what you've done to instead update `span.style.textOverflow`

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with CSS. The problem is that HTML and CSS are supposed to work in a variety of browsers and fonts and it is almost impossible to calculate the width of a string in a consistent way. This is an [idea](http://robrohan.com/2006/01/20/javascript-string-width-in-pixels/) that might help you. However, you would need to do that a number of times, until you find the string with the appropriate width.

Comment: I'm interested in your opinion on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36470401/506954

Answer (score 2):

Another stab:

```
function truncate( str, max, sep ) {
    max = max || 10;
    var len = str.length;
    if(len > max){
        sep = sep || "...";
        var seplen = sep.length;
        if(seplen > max) { 
            return str.substring(len - max)
        }
        var n = -0.5 * (max - len - seplen);
        var center = len/2;
        return str.substring(0, center - n) + sep + str.substring(len - center + n);
    }
    return str;
}

console.log( truncate("123456789abcde") ); // 123...bcde (using built-in defaults) 
console.log( truncate("123456789abcde", 8) ); // 12...cde (max of 8 characters) 
console.log( truncate("123456789abcde", 12, "_") ); // 12345_9abcde (customize the separator)
```

Comment: This is a lovely function. In 2022 though, `substr` is deprecated. `substring` is recommended now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the shortest bit I could find which replaces 3 characters in the middle with ....

```
function shorten(s, max) {
  return s.length > max ? s.substring(0, (max / 2) - 1) + '...' + s.substring(s.length - (max / 2) + 2, s.length) : s
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an elegant solution:

```
function truncateMiddle(word) {
    const tooLongChars = 15; // arbitrary

    if (word.length < tooLongChars) {
        return word;
    }

    const ellipsis = '...';
    const charsOnEitherSide = Math.floor(tooLongChars / 2) - ellipsis.length;

    return word.slice(0, charsOnEitherSide) + ellipsis + word.slice(-charsOnEitherSide);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[edit] Firefox only solution until other browsers support a string value for `text-overflow`; see https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_text-overflow_string

---

Here is a rather involved solution which uses javascript, but only so far as to modify the `textOverflow` style property on the element, and so can fall back on existing CSS (if the element later expands, the ellipsis will disappear).

When calculating the mid point, it takes into account varying widths of characters, by bypassing the characters themselves, and instead looking at the width of text selections on those characters.

Unlike the other solutions I've seen so far (apart from [Ale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68407312/6691)'s), it also doesn't actually mess with the DOM text content itself, but rather copies the tail of the content into CSS, so screen readers etc. should be unaffected.

I've set a max height of `2em` to demonstrate how this works for multiline paragraphs also, but this bit is optional.

A TODO is that you'd need to re-run the `applyMidOverflow` function over elements if their width changes (this can be seen by manipulating the resize control at bottom right of the demo below).

```js
function applyMidOverflow(el, delimiter) {
    if (delimiter === undefined || 
        Number.isInteger(delimiter)  // forEach index
       ) {
        var cs = getComputedStyle(el);     
        if (cs.textOverflow === 'ellipsis' || cs.textOverflow === '') {
            delimiter = '…';
        } else {
            // remove quotes
            delimiter = s.textOverflow.substring(1, s.textOverflow.length - 1)
        }
    }
    var r = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var half_width_pos = r.x + (r.width/2);    
    if (el.childNodes.length !== 1 || el.childNodes[0].nodeType !== 3) {
        console.warn('midOverflow: need a single TEXT_NODE child', el);
        return;
    }    
    const textChild = el.childNodes[0];
    var range = document.createRange();    
    var end = textChild.textContent.length;

    // set the following to zero to be sure
    var approx_mid = Math.round(end * 0.4);

    for (var i = approx_mid; i < end; i++) {
        // TODO: binary search
        range.setStart(textChild, i);
        range.setEnd(textChild, end);
        // not getBoundingClientRect as word could wrap
        var rects = range.getClientRects();
        var selected_t = Array.from(rects, (r)=>r.width).reduce((a, b)=>a+b, 0);
        if (selected_t < half_width_pos) {
            break;   
        }        
    }   
    el.style.textOverflow = '" ' + delimiter + ' ' + textChild.textContent.substring(i).replace(/"/, '\\"').replace('\n', '').replace(/\s+$/g, '') + '"';
}

addEventListener('load', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.overflow-mid').forEach(applyMidOverflow);    
});
```

```css
.overflow-mid {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* will be overwritten */
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="resize:both;overflow:auto;width:75%">

<div class="overflow-mid">Multi line ipsum dolor amet meatball bresaola t-bone tri-tip brisket. Jowl pig picanha cupim landjaeger, frankfurter spare ribs chicken. Porchetta jowl panhttps://jsfiddle.net/amvebozn/2/#runcetta drumstick shankle cow spare ribs jerky tail kevin biltong capicola brisket venison bresaola. Flank sirloin jowl andouille meatball venison salami ground round rump boudin turkey capicola t-bone. Sirloin filet mignon tenderloin beef, biltong doner bresaola brisket shoulder pork loin shankle turducken shank cow. Ragged end of multi line.
</div>    

<div class="overflow-mid">"The true sign of intelligence is not knowledge but imagination."</div>
<br>
<div class="overflow-mid">"Albert Einstein likely didn't utter the majority of the many quotes that are attributed to him."</div>
<div class="overflow-mid">"You can't blame gravity for falling in love."</div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amvebozn/5/

Comment: I like the consideration of accessibility, however both SO snippet and jsfiddle only show ellipses at the end of the strings, not in the middle as requested by OP.

Comment: Ah apologies, I now realize my solution is Firefox only for now (although it does fall back gracefully); I've updated the answer with a disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a mix of the above solutions and puts the last whole word at the end of the shortened text. However in case the last word is longer then a third of the available space it is also shortend from the left. If a dash("-") is found, cut it of there, if not, cut it of anyway.

```
function truncate(text, textLimit) {
    if (!text) return text;
    if (textLimit < 1) return string;
    if (text.length < textLimit) return text;
    if (textLimit === 1) return text.substring(0,1) + '...';
    /* extract the last word */
    var lastPart = text.slice( string.lastIndexOf(' ')+1 );
    /* if last word is longer then a third of the max available space
       cut it from the left */
    var lastPartLimit = Math.ceil(textLimit / 3);
    if(lastPart.length > lastPartLimit) {
        var truncatedLastPart = lastPart;
        /* Try to find a dash and cut the last word there */
        var lastDashPart = text.slice( text.lastIndexOf('-')+1 );
        if(lastDashPart.length < lastPartLimit){
            truncatedLastPart = lastDashPart;
        }
        /* If the last part is still to long or not available cut it anyway */
        if(truncatedLastPart.length > lastPartLimit) {
            var lastIndex = lastPart.length - lastPartLimit;
            truncatedLastPart = lastPart.substring( lastIndex );
        }
        lastPart = truncatedLastPart;
    }
    var dots = '... ';
    var firsPartLength = textLimit - lastPart.length - dots.length;
    return text.substring(0, firstPartLength) + dots + lastPart;
}

console.log( truncate("New York City", 10) ); // Ne... City (max of 10 characters)
console.log( truncate("New York Kindergarden", 14) ); // Ne...ergarden (max of 14 characters, last word gets cut from the left by a third)
console.log( truncate("New York Kinder-garden", 14) ); // Ne...garden (max of 14 characters, last word gets cut by the dash from the left)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created a function that can trim at the middle, nearEnd and End but havent been tested yet because I finally was needing it at the server side

```
//position acceptable values : middle, end, closeEnd
function AddElipsis(input, maxChars, position) {
    if (typeof input === 'undefined') {
        return "";
    }
    else if (input.length <= maxChars) {
        return input;
    }
    else {
        if (position == 'middle') {
            var midPos = Math.floor(maxChars / 2) - 2;
            return input.substr(0, midPos) + '...' + input.substr(input.length - midPos, input.length);
        }
        else if (position == 'closeEnd') {
            var firstPart = Math.floor(maxChars * 0.80) - 2;
            var endPart = Math.floor(maxChars * 0.20) - 2;
            return input.substr(0, firstPart) + '...' + input.substr(input.length - endPart, input.length);
        }
        else {
            return input.substr(0, maxChars - 3) + '...';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a little more control over the position of the ellipsis and the placeholder text:

```
function ellipsis(str, maxLength, ellipsisLocationPercentage,placeholder) {
    /*
    ARGUMENTS:
    str - the string you want to maninpulate
    maxLength -  max number of characters allowed in return string
    ellipsisLocationPercentage (optional) - How far (percentage wise) into the return string you want the ellipses to be placed
        Examples:
        .85 : This is a very long string. This is a very long string. This is a very long string. This is a ver[...]very long string.
        .25 : This is a very long string. [...]g. This is a very long string. This is a very long string. This is a very long string.
    placeholder (optional) - this will be used to replace the removed substring. Suggestions : '...', '[..]', '[ ... ]', etc....
    */
    if(ellipsisLocationPercentage == null || isNaN(ellipsisLocationPercentage) || ellipsisLocationPercentage >= 1 || ellipsisLocationPercentage <= 0){
        //we've got null or bad data.. default to something fun, like 85% (that's fun, right??)
        ellipsisLocationPercentage = .85;
    }
    if(placeholder == null || placeholder ==""){
        placeholder = "[...]";
    }

    if (str.length > (maxLength-placeholder.length)) {
        //get the end of the string
        var beginning = str.substr(0, (maxLength - placeholder.length)*ellipsisLocationPercentage );
        var end = str.substr(str.length-(maxLength - placeholder.length) * (1-ellipsisLocationPercentage));
        return beginning + placeholder + end;
    }
    return str;
}
```

You can call this function by calling:

```
ellipsis("This is a very long string. Be Scared!!!!", 8);//uses default values
ellipsis("This is a very long string. Be Scared!!!!", 8,.5);//puts ellipsis at half way point
ellipsis("This is a very long string. Be Scared!!!!", 8,.75,'<..>');//puts ellipsis at 75% of the way into the string and uses '<..>' as the placeholder
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a clean cut and have a whole word at the end of the shortened text, I used the below function.

```js
function prepareText(text){
  var returnString = text;
  var textLimit = 35;
  if(text.length > textLimit){
    var lastWord = text.slice( text.lastIndexOf(' ')+1 );
    var indexFromEnd = lastWord.length;
    var ellipsis = '... ';

    returnString = text.slice(0, textLimit - indexFromEnd - ellipsis.length);
    returnString = returnString + ellipsis + lastWord;
  }
  return returnString;
}

$('#ex1Modified').html( prepareText( $('#ex1').html() ) );

$('#ex2Modified').html( prepareText( $('#ex2').html() ) );

$('#ex3Modified').html( prepareText( $('#ex3').html() ) );
```

```css
body{color:#777; font-family: sans-serif;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Shortened Quotes from Albert Einstein</h2>

<div id="ex1">"The true sign of intelligence is not knowledge but imagination."</div>
<div id="ex1Modified"></div>
<br>
<div id="ex2">"Look deep into nature, and then you will understand everything better."</div>
<div id="ex2Modified"></div>
<br>
<div id="ex3">"You can't blame gravity for falling in love."</div>
<div id="ex3Modified"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it – a CSS-only solution that sadly only works in Firefox right now:

```css
div {
  width: 20em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: " … is also your text.";
}
```

```html
<div>Here's the long string of letters that accidentally is also your text.</div>
```

You can specify the second `text-overflow` declaration directly on the element if you need your text to be dynamic. Browsers that do not support this syntax (Chrome, notably :-) will fall back to plain old ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

** CSS solution **

Nowadays, can organize this with pure CSS, or CSS and some js to detect text overflow. It does not show partial letters.

The idea is:

Use word-wrapping for the left part. Use original ellipsis truncation with `direction: rtl` - that makes it appear to the left of the text and nicely truncates it at the left side letter-by-letter. Ellipsis displayed ourselves to make it always in the center, then we hide the original ellipsis by the rgba transparent color override.

Disadvantages:

- text color needs to be defined as a variable and there is no way to use currentColor (if this is critically needed, you can use the original ellipsis from the right side of the text, but this would not always look nicely, ellipsis will jump around not always centered)
- duplicate text use in HTML (not a big issue for React/Vue or similar apps)
- special characters in the text, if appear on the right side, may render in the wrong order, because of `direction: rtl`. This works well for

Do not make too many of these on a single page, may slow down rendering.

Below is a simple example (accurate displaying of the overflown text only), can show this by JS when overflow is detected. A more complex example, based on the same idea, that is CSS-only can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/4furv8c2/

```css
.middle-truncate {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--color);
}

.middle-truncate-l {
  text-align: left;
  width: calc(50% - 0.5em);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.middle-truncate-r {
  text-align: left;
  width: calc(50% + 0.4em);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  direction: rtl;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.middle-truncate-r span {
  color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<div class='middle-truncate' style="--color: blue; width: 40%; font-size: 40px; -font-family: 'Courier New';">
  …
  <div class='middle-truncate-l'>
    This is a long text to truncate
  </div>
  <div class='middle-truncate-r'>
    <span>This is a long text to truncate</span>
  </div>
</div>
```