# Truncating text and append an ellipsis using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, truncate

How can I truncate a string and append an ellipsis (...)?

I want to truncate something like `'this is a very long string'` to `'this is a ve...'`

Comment: Do you mean to truncate something like `'this is a very long string'` to `'this is a ve...'` etc?

Comment: Can you provide and example?   And what do you mean by TEXT?

Comment: @jzd please see this screenshot http://i964.photobucket.com/albums/ae123/DollarFriend/well.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [smart way to shorten long strings with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199352/smart-way-to-shorten-long-strings-with-javascript)

Answer (score 204):

```js
function truncate(input) {
   if (input.length > 5) {
      return input.substring(0, 5) + '...';
   }
   return input;
};
```

or in ES6

```js
const truncate = (input) => input.length > 5 ? `${input.substring(0, 5)}...` : input;
```

Comment: This (string.substr(0,5)+'...';) worked for me.

Comment: If you want to please typographers you can use `…` which is a dedicated glyph for ellipsis where the space between the dots is a bit narrower.

Answer (score 45):

KooiInc has a good answer to this. To summarise:

```
String.prototype.trunc = 
      function(n){
          return this.substr(0,n-1)+(this.length>n?'&hellip;':'');
      };
```

Now you can do:

```
var s = 'not very long';
s.trunc(25); //=> not very long
s.trunc(5); //=> not...
```

---

And if you prefer it as a function, as per @AlienLifeForm's comment:

```
function truncateWithEllipses(text, max) 
{
    return text.substr(0,max-1)+(text.length>max?'&hellip;':''); 
}
```

*Full credit goes to [KooiInc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1199420/577306) for this.*

Comment: Concise is nice. I used it as: `function truncateWithEllipses(text, max) {return text.substr(0,max-1)+(text.length>max?'&hellip;':''); }`

Comment: I like the solution from comment above @AlienLifeForm very elegant

Comment: This is a good one-liner but it truncates the string even when its length doesn't exceed the limit. I would add a conditional (ES6 example): `export const characterLimit = (text, limit) => text.length > limit ? (text.substr(0, limit - 1).trim() + '...') : text;`

Comment: ES6 function with ending argument:
`truncateWithEllipses = (text, max, ending = '…') => text.length > max ? text.substr(0, max - ending.length) + ending : text;`

Comment: @KévinBerthommier Probably shouldn't be called `truncateWithEllipses` if you're also providing a `ending` param, since you can change what the `ending` is and then it is no longer `WithEllipses`.

Comment: Wouldnt directly add functionalities to the prototype .

Answer (score 17):

**This will limit it to however many lines you want it limited to and is responsive**

An idea that nobody has suggested, doing it based on the height of the element and then stripping it back from there.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hutber/u5mtLznf/ <- ES6 version

But basically you want to grab the line height of the element, loop through all the text and stop when its at a certain lines height:

```
'use strict';

var linesElement = 3; //it will truncate at 3 lines.
var truncateElement = document.getElementById('truncateme');
var truncateText = truncateElement.textContent;

var getLineHeight = function getLineHeight(element) {
  var lineHeight = window.getComputedStyle(truncateElement)['line-height'];
  if (lineHeight === 'normal') {
    // sucky chrome
    return 1.16 * parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(truncateElement)['font-size']);
  } else {
    return parseFloat(lineHeight);
  }
};

linesElement.addEventListener('change', function () {
  truncateElement.innerHTML = truncateText;
  var truncateTextParts = truncateText.split(' ');
  var lineHeight = getLineHeight(truncateElement);
  var lines = parseInt(linesElement.value);

  while (lines * lineHeight < truncateElement.clientHeight) {
    console.log(truncateTextParts.length, lines * lineHeight, truncateElement.clientHeight);
    truncateTextParts.pop();
    truncateElement.innerHTML = truncateTextParts.join(' ') + '...';
  }
});
```

### ES6

```
const linesElement=document.getElementById('lines');
const truncateElement=document.getElementById('truncateme');
const truncateText=truncateElement.textContent;


const getLineHeight = function(element) {
  const lineHeight = window.getComputedStyle(truncateElement)['line-height'];
  if (lineHeight === 'normal') {
    // fuck chrome
    return 1.16 * parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(truncateElement)['font-size']);
  } else {
    return parseFloat(lineHeight);
  }
}

linesElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
  truncateElement.innerHTML=truncateText
  const truncateTextParts= truncateText.split(' ');
  const lineHeight = getLineHeight(truncateElement);
  const lines = parseInt(linesElement.value);
  
  while(lines * lineHeight < truncateElement.clientHeight) {
    console.log(truncateTextParts.length, lines * lineHeight , truncateElement.clientHeight)
    truncateTextParts.pop();
    truncateElement.innerHTML = truncateTextParts.join(' ') + '...';
  }
})
```

**CSS**

```
#truncateme {
   width: auto; This will be completely dynamic to the height of the element, its just restricted by how many lines you want it to clip to
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Something like:

```
var line = "foo bar lol";
line.substring(0, 5) + '...' // gives "foo b..."
```

Comment: This is not a complete solution. You need to check if the string is actually bigger than the amount you are going to truncate. If false, then the `...` should not appear. Just using `line.substring(0, max_char)` won't be a sufficient enough solution.

Comment: Upvoted for terseness. OP did not specify threshold requirement.

Answer (score 9):

This will put the ellipsis in the center of the line:

```
function truncate( str, max, sep ) {

    // Default to 10 characters
    max = max || 10;

    var len = str.length;
    if(len > max){

        // Default to elipsis
        sep = sep || "...";

        var seplen = sep.length;

        // If seperator is larger than character limit,
        // well then we don't want to just show the seperator,
        // so just show right hand side of the string.
        if(seplen > max) {
            return str.substr(len - max);
        }

        // Half the difference between max and string length.
        // Multiply negative because small minus big.
        // Must account for length of separator too.
        var n = -0.5 * (max - len - seplen);

        // This gives us the centerline.
        var center = len/2;

        var front = str.substr(0, center - n);
        var back = str.substr(len - center + n); // without second arg, will automatically go to end of line.

        return front + sep + back;

    }

    return str;
}

console.log( truncate("123456789abcde") ); // 123...bcde (using built-in defaults) 
console.log( truncate("123456789abcde", 8) ); // 12...cde (max of 8 characters) 
console.log( truncate("123456789abcde", 12, "_") ); // 12345_9abcde (customize the separator)
```

For example:

```
1234567890 --> 1234...8910
```

And:

```
A really long string --> A real...string
```

Not perfect, but functional. Forgive the over-commenting... for the noobs.

Comment: Some other similar functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831552/ellipsis-in-the-middle-of-a-text-mac-style/30613599#30613599

Answer (score 8):

For preventing the dots in the middle of a word or after a punctuation symbol.

```js
let parseText = function(text, limit){
  if (text.length > limit){
      for (let i = limit; i > 0; i--){
          if(text.charAt(i) === ' ' && (text.charAt(i-1) != ','||text.charAt(i-1) != '.'||text.charAt(i-1) != ';')) {
              return text.substring(0, i) + '...';
          }
      }
       return text.substring(0, limit) + '...';
  }
  else
      return text;
};
    
    
console.log(parseText("1234567 890",5))  // >> 12345...
console.log(parseText("1234567 890",8))  // >> 1234567...
console.log(parseText("1234567 890",15)) // >> 1234567 890
```

Comment: I liked your solution but your function had a bug without `return text.substring(0, limit) + '...';`. I edited your answer and added that line to your code + some other micro changes. Without that line, `parseText("1234567 890",5)` return `undefined` but now it works well.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest and flexible way: [**JSnippet DEMO**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/244/truncate-a-text-or-line-with-ellipsis-using-JavaScript)

Function style:

```
function truncString(str, max, add){
   add = add || '...';
   return (typeof str === 'string' && str.length > max ? str.substring(0,max)+add : str);
};
```

Prototype:

```
String.prototype.truncString = function(max, add){
   add = add || '...';
   return (this.length > max ? this.substring(0,max)+add : this);
};
```

Usage:

```
str = "testing with some string see console output";

//By prototype:
console.log(  str.truncString(15,'...')  );

//By function call:
console.log(  truncString(str,15,'...')  );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function truncate(string, length, delimiter) {
   delimiter = delimiter || "&hellip;";
   return string.length > length ? string.substr(0, length) + delimiter : string;
};

var long = "Very long text here and here",
    short = "Short";

truncate(long, 10); // -> "Very long ..."
truncate(long, 10, ">>"); // -> "Very long >>"
truncate(short, 10); // -> "Short"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function shorten(text, maxLength, delimiter, overflow) {
  delimiter = delimiter || "&hellip;";
  overflow = overflow || false;
  var ret = text;
  if (ret.length > maxLength) {
    var breakpoint = overflow ? maxLength + ret.substr(maxLength).indexOf(" ") : ret.substr(0, maxLength).lastIndexOf(" ");
    ret = ret.substr(0, breakpoint) + delimiter;
  }
  return ret;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $editedText = $("#edited_text");
  var text = $editedText.text();
  $editedText.text(shorten(text, 33, "...", false));
});
```

Checkout a working sample on Codepen
http://codepen.io/Izaias/pen/QbBwwE

Answer (score 0):

HTML with JavaScript:

```
<p id="myid">My long long looooong text cut cut cut cut cut</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myid=document.getElementById('myid');
myid.innerHTML=myid.innerHTML.substring(0,10)+'...';
</script>
```

The result will be:

```
My long lo...
```

Cheers

G.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut a string for a specifited length and add dots use

```
// Length to cut
var lengthToCut = 20;

// Sample text
var text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

// We are getting 50 letters (0-50) from sample text
var cutted = text.substr(0, lengthToCut );
document.write(cutted+"...");
```

Or if you want to cut not by length but with words count use:

```
// Number of words to cut
var wordsToCut = 3;

// Sample text
var text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

// We are splitting sample text in array of words
var wordsArray = text.split(" ");

// This will keep our generated text
var cutted = "";
for(i = 0; i < wordsToCut; i++)
 cutted += wordsArray[i] + " "; // Add to cutted word with space

document.write(cutted+"...");
```

Good luck...

Comment: This adds ellipsis to all strings even if they aren't cut...