# Add dots at a position in text without truncating words

Tags: javascript, string, truncate

How to add the three dots at a position in the text and prevent these three dots from truncating any word or being placed after puntuation marks (.,;:)?

This is my javascript function

```
let parseText = function(text, limit){
    return text.substring(0, limit) + '...';
};
```

Comment: I was looking for preventing placing the three dots after puntuation points too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42256471/5195127) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700226/i-want-to-truncate-a-text-or-line-with-ellipsis-using-javascript/42256471#42256471) post will help you:

For preventing the dots in the middle of a word or after a punctuation symbol.

```
let parseText = function(text, limit){
if (text.length > limit)
    for (let i = limit; i > 0; i--){
        if(text.charAt(i) === ' ' && (text.charAt(i-1) != ','||text.charAt(i-1) != '.'||text.charAt(i-1) != ';')) {
            return text.substring(0, i) + '...';
        }
    }
else
    return text;
};
```