# Hiding the middle of overflown text in HTML

Tags: html

Is it at all possible to hide the middle of overflown text instead of the end? Such as replacing the overflown text with periods.

I'm specifically talking about in a table now, but any possible way would be good to know.

So I mean shortening `112233445566778899` to `112...899` (or something similar) instead of `11223344`

I don't know too much of JavaScript but if this is the only way let me know how and I'll figure out the rest with tutorials.

Comment: I think you should use javascript for this. are you ok to use it?

Comment: I know javascript is an answer for this but I'm eager to know if there is actually a way in HTML or CSS only. not op -->

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overflow:hidden dots at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486563/overflowhidden-dots-at-the-end)

Comment: @Mr_Green JavaScript would be ok, I know a lot of Python and I'd have to figure out JS with tutorials.

Comment: Is it a fixed container or fluid one?

Comment: @PatsyIssa The question specifically says that the dots should be in the middle, not at the end.

Comment: Even with javascript I presume it as challenging +1'ed

Comment: @Juhana Then make the div smaller?

Comment: Simple enough to do in Javascript - http://jsfiddle.net/qHALz/

Comment: @NickR This should be a answer.

Comment: @PatsyIssa That would still not put the dots in the middle. For a string "abcdefg" the OP wants "ab...fg", not "abdc..."

Comment: @Juhana Oh my bad you are right

Comment: @LuukV I came to the party a bit late, but I believe my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23956645/1317805) addresses everything you've specified in this question and on other answers' comments.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly yeah you did! Now it looks like its not working due to the way I've been setting up the HTML or CSS. I'm going to figure out what to do with this but thanks a lot for the answer, I will definitely use it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've come up with a pure-JavaScript solution which combines [Nick R's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23955659/1317805) and [alhoseany's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533267/alhoseany) answers together, whilst adding in a few extra bits of functionality to detect length and specify the number of characters required either side of the ellipsis.

With this method you do not need to know the number of characters that can fit in your container, it's all done automatically and can also be triggered when the window resizes.

## [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fSm9t/5/).

**Resize the result frame to see the results in action.**

## Result

This:

[image: Initial Example]

...becomes this:

[image: Example]

...or this:

[image: Example 2]

...or this!

[image: Example 3]

## The Code

### CSS

```css
p {
    border: 1px dashed #000;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
}

p:before {
    content:attr(data-shortened);
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
function shortenContent(content, chars) {
    /* chars here determines how many characters
     * we want on either side of the elipsis. */
    var chars = chars || 3; // Default is 3
    
    if (!content && !content.length)
        return;
    
    /* Loop through each content element and
     * shorten where necessary. */
    for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        var el = content[i],
            elementWidth = el.offsetWidth,
            textWidth = el.scrollWidth;
        
        /* If our element's width is less than
         * its content's width, we need to shorten. */
        if (elementWidth < textWidth) {
            var text = el.innerText;
            /* Set the data attribute for the CSS to use. */
            el.setAttribute(
              'data-shortened', text.slice(0,chars) +'...'+ text.slice(-chars)
            );
            el.style.color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
        }
        /* Otherwise, ensure non-shortened text is visible. */
        else {
            el.setAttribute('data-shortened', '');
            el.style.color = null;
        }
    }
}
```

## How do I use it?

To use the above function, you simply need to pass in a collection of elements into the `shortenContent` function:

```
// Get the content we wish to shorten
var content = document.querySelectorAll('div p');

/* Trigger the function initially. */
shortenContent(content);
```

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz    =>    abc...xyz
```

### Specifying a different number of characters

If you want a different number of characters to appear before and after the ellipsis (e.g. `abcd...wxyz` instead of `abc...xyz`), you can pass in a number as a second argument into the `shortenContent` function:

```
/* Trigger the function initially. */
shortenContent(content, 4);
```

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz    =>    abcd...wxyz
```

#### Window Resize example

This will fire the `shortenContent` function whenever the window (the JSFiddle result pane, in this case) changes size.

```
/* Fire the shorten function when the window resizes. */
window.onresize = function(event) {
    shortenContent(content);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Javascript, you could do something like this:

```
function shortenNum(num){

    if(num.length > 6){
        var first = num.slice(0, 3); 
        var last = num.slice(-3); 
        //console.log(first + "..." + last );
        alert(first + "..." + last );
    } else {
        alert(num)
    }
}

// should return 112...899
shortenNum("112233445566778899");
shortenNum("19999");
shortenNum("3536355");
```

It takes in a string, and grabs the first 3 characters and the last 3, then we can just concatenate them together, plus the `...`

You could use `substring` as well instead of `slice`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qHALz/5/)**

*edit*: added a check for string length, anything over 6 characters should be shortened.

Comment: Nice. Didn't see you already have answered. Have also an answer basedd on your concept. I hope it is ok.

Comment: But what if my number is only `123`? http://jsfiddle.net/qHALz/4/ You should add some length checking in there.

Comment: As I said, it would be challenging if we consider all cases like a fluid container. Even here you are not considering fixed width. I am not sure whether OP is satisfied with this..

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yeah I should probably work on my defensive coding :p

Comment: @NickR I decided to go ahead and combine this answer with allhoseany's below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23956645/1317805

Answer (score 3):

Here is a anonymously Javascript Example

**This is the Js** (Based on Nick R's Comment)

```
$('.shortable').each(function(index) {
    //Get the Text
    var text = $(this).text();

    //Get the wanted Length
    var wantedLength = $(this).data('length')

    //Get the current Length
    var currentLength = text.length

    //If it should be shorten
    if (wantedLength < currentLength) {
        //Get Half Length
        var halfLength = Math.round(wantedLength / 2)

        //Get the Text Parts
        var first = text.slice(0, halfLength); 
        var last = text.slice(0-halfLength); 

        //Change the Text
        $(this).text(first + "..." + last);
    }
});
```

**This is the Html** (Look at the Attributes):

```
<p class="shortable" data-length="20">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<p class="shortable" data-length="20">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

**This is the Output:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor

Lorem ipsu... sit amet.
```

**And this is your Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/qHALz/6/

**And this is your additional Question**

> Is there a simple Js way of applying it on everything that would actually overflow and not on things that don't?

You can append the class `shortable` and the `data-length` Attribute to all those Elements.

For Example

```
<span class="shortable" data-length="20">Lorem Ipsum...</span>
<i class="shortable" data-length="20">Lorem Ipsum...</i>
<a class="shortable" data-length="20">Lorem Ipsum...</a>
```

Comment: :) Nice. A bit more flexible than mine.

Comment: This is perfect. Is there a simple Js way of applying it on everything that would actually overflow and not on things that don't?

Comment: Just add a class of `shortable` to the overflowing elements. So `<span class="shortable">4353453454543534</span>` and the `.each` means it loops through all the elements with that class, and runs the function.

Comment: @LuukV Edited, so it also work if the text is shorter then `data-length` (20)

Answer (score 2):

With CSS, its not possible to *clip* or *ellipse* in mid text

[**Quoting W3C :**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Text-overflow_middle_cropping)

> Existing behavior
>
> According to the description of text-overflow at Mozilla and the
>   definition in the current W3C CSS UI module spec there's currently
>   only the possibility to clip strings at the beginning and their end.

Only Possible Solution is from JavaScript, this thread would help you:

**[Ellipsis in the middle of a text (Mac style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831552/ellipsis-in-the-middle-of-a-text-mac-style)**

Answer (score 2):

there is a ways to do this with html and css:

you can use the css pseudo elements with content property to replace the numbers with any attribute content like title or data-numbers.

example:

```
<div class="target" data-numbers="112...899" ><span>112233445566778899</span></div>

.target span{
    display:none;
}
.target:before{
    content:attr(data-numbers);    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cUrjH/